# Make a random correlation matrix semi definite positive

Tags: r, matrix, random

I am trying to make a random matrix correlation over 183 variables to calculate a Cholesky decomposition and correlate 183 random normals. For the creation of the correlation matrix the following reproducible code is the one I am using:

First I set the seed

```
set.seed(2)
```

Then I generate random numbers between 0.6 and 0.8

```
corr <- matrix(runif(183*183, min = 0.6, max = 0.8), 183, 183)
```

The next step is turning the diagonal into ones

```
for (i in 1:183) {
  for (j in 1:183) {
    if (i == j) {
    corr[i,j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

Last step is making it symmetric

```
for (i in 1:183) {
  for (j in 1:183) {
    if (i < j) {
    corr[i,j] <- corr[j,i]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I run into arise when I try to make the cholesky decomposition

```
cholesky <- chol(corr)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in chol.default(corr) : 
>     the leading minor of order 14 is not positive definite

How could I make my correlation matrix semi definite positive?

Comment: Not an answer : But you can set diagonal to 1 by doing `diag(corr) <- 1`

Comment: Semi-positive definite matrices are not defined by once on the diagonal elements and symmetry. This question is more a mathematical question rather than a R code question. You may follow https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab

Comment: @Freakazoid, thanks for your answer, I think I am aware of what semi-definite positive matrix means, however, I have looked up how to do it in R and I can't get any ideas for a concrete case of a correlation matrix, My question is more about how to do it to this concrete case in R

Comment: @Mauro You can generate a random covariance matrix with a Wishart distribution, and turn it into a correlation matrix with `cov2cor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below to generate semi-definite positive matrix

```
set.seed(2)
v <- runif(183,0.6,0.8)
corr <- `diag<-`(tcrossprod(v),1)
```

Comment: upvoted. maybe can improve on the answer by referring to literature on numerical stability of covariance matrices. and why using t(X) %*% X helps to generate a stable one